# How to match columns in a scrolling table with fixed headers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to create a scrolling table with a fixed header. Problem is that the columns between the `<thead>` and the `<tbody>` are not matched correctly. My question is how can I get the columns to match in a scrolling table with fixed headers.

Below is the fiddle, just click on the "Add Question" button 3 times and then scroll the table:

http://jsfiddle.net/6rCyH/2/

Below is the html of the table:

```
<table id="qandatbl" align="center">
<thead class="tblhead">
<tr>
    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
    <th class="question">Question</th>
    <th class="optandans">Option and Answer</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tblbody">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the main css which controls the table and each column:

```
body{
    font-size:85%;  
}           

.extratd{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.qid { 
    min-width:3%;
    max-width:3%;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.question { 
    min-width:14%;
    max-width:14%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.question textarea {
    min-width:auto;
    max-width:auto;
    resize:none;
    height:100%;
    font-size:100%;
}

.noofanswers{
    min-width:15%;
    max-width:15%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

.optandans{
    min-width:30%;
    max-width:30%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.option{
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

.answer { 
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
     }   

.tblbody{
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto; 
}

.tblhead, .tblbody {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create scrollable table with fixed headers, but when you append the table rows into the table by clicking on `Add Question` the columns do not match between `thead` and `tbody`. The classes for the thead columns and the associated tbody columns are the same but yet they do not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result
[image]

with the following CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
        .qid {
            width:15%;
        }

        .question {
            width:30%;
        }

        .extratd {
            /*
             * width will be the remaining of its parent.
             */
        }
        table {
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        td, th {
            border:1px solid black;
            /*
             * In case the long word will affect the width of TD
             */
            word-wrap:break-word;
            word-break:break-all;
        }
        thead {
            /*
             * minus the scollbar's width from THEAD
             */
            margin-right:12px;
        }
        thead, tbody {
            /*
             * Override the default display table-head-group, table-row-group.
             * If not, the height will be computed with table layout rendering algorithm
             * by browser
             */
            display:block;
        }
        tbody {
            /*
             * let the TABLE BODY part scroll
             */
            height:400px;
            overflow:scroll;
        }
        tbody td {
            /* In case the children in the TD will change its width which 
             * set by CSS implicitly, such as 15%, 30%
             */
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        textarea {
            /* to override the default width of text area in case it will 
             * go out of TD */
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
```

See the comments inline. There is a problem for this solution, we have to know the width of scroll bar, so the compatibility won't be good.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="qid">Question No</th>
                <th class="question">Question</th>
                <th class="extratd">Option and Answer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr align="center" class="optionAndAnswer">
                <td class="qid">1</td>
                <td class="question">                   
                    <textarea class="textAreaQuestion" name="questionText[]" value=""></textarea>
                </td>
                <td class="extratd">
                <div class="option">
                    1. Option Type:
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="gridTxtRow maxRow" name="gridValues[]" value="">
                    <span class="showGrid" href="#">[Open Grid]</span>
                </div>
                <div class="noofanswers">
                    2. Number of Answers:
                    <br>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="naRow string" name="numberAnswer[]" value="">Only 1 Answer</span>
                    <input type="text" onchange="getButtons()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="numberKeyUp(this)" style="display: block;" class="numberAnswerTxtRow answertxt" name="numberAnswer[]" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    3. Answer:
                    <br>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I don't know how you got itexactly working because in my app I can;t get it to work. Can you modify the fiddle (only the css part, not the html part and achieve the same result?) Like I said the table columns have to be aligned correctly and it has to work for any computer screen, it can't be out of place because of bigger or smaller screen. Upvoted answer but at mo can't quite accept it yet

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6rCyH/49/ tested on FF15+, chorom 23, IE9(no scrollbar) However, the way you are on to deal with "table with fixed head" is not perfect. Search the issue and many good solutions for it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this part from the end of your CSS:

```
.tblhead, .tblbody {
    display: block;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/DC4Ps/1/

Comment: But then I do not get a scrolling table with fixed headers. I want columns to match but I still want scrolling table with fixed headers

Comment: have you got any more ideas to add to this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible purely in css, unless you specify the width of each column (i.e. manually align the columns rather than automatically). You could use percentages to align the columns, but then when the scrollbar appears they get misaligned again. Fixed column widths would work fine (see Chanckjh's answer). Another alternative is to use javascript. Something like [this](http://www.tablefixedheader.com) might work.

Comment: You could set `overflow-y: scroll` on both the table head and body to stop the scrollbar misaligning the columns. And why do you set `min-width` and `max-width` but not `width`?

Comment: The reason I set min-width and max width is because before you append a row, I want the table headings to remain the same width throughout, I am quite sure that if I change it to just width, then the table headings will decrease to size where text fits inside and that is it, it doesn't expand to its full width. So to make sure i set a max and min width, I will try normal width as you mentioned and see what happens and I will try the overflow-y:scroll method you mentioned and get back to you

Comment: ok I have upvoted your answer as the idea of the scrollbar you mentioned was genius. Now the only factor is the columns alignments. What I don't quite understand is that the class for the table headers `<th>` and the `<td>` tags which appear underneath have the same classes as the associated table headers (except for options and answers column). So what I don't understand is why can't they match the same width?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
question textarea { min-width: auto; max-width: auto; resize: none; height: 240px; font-size: 100%; border: none;

Comment: Hi, if I do this the only issue is the question number column, That column doesn't match. What property will I need to change there?

Comment: Have you got any ideas on this?

Comment: I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't match?  I show it being the same height as the other two columns.

Comment: I mean if you look at the aligning of the columns after I append a table row, they are out of place. A table cell for question number is a lot smaller than the table cell of it heading above for example. They should be equal. This is same outcome I want the other 2 columns to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using percentages? If you use px everything should be fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/6rCyH/5/

```
            /*css for QandATable.php*/
body{
    font-size:85%;    
}            

#qandatbl{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#qandatbl td { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#qandatbl th{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}

.extratd{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.qid { 
    min-width:76px;
    max-width:3%;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.question { 
    min-width:177px;
    max-width:177px;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.question textarea {
    min-width:auto;
    max-width:auto;
    resize:none;
    height:100%;
    font-size:100%;
}

.noofanswers{
    min-width:15%;
    max-width:15%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

.optandans{
    min-width:194px;
    max-width:30%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.option{
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

.answer { 
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
     }


.wrapper{
    text-align:left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#question{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;    
    min-width:25%;
    max-width:25%;
}

#question th{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid black;    
    position: fixed;
}

#question td{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid black;    
}

#optionAndAnswer{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    min-width:28%;
    max-width:28%;
}

#optionAndAnswer th{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid black;    
}

#optionAndAnswer td{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid black;    
}

#optionAndAnswer td table td {
    border: 0px;   
}

#answerSection{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;    
}


#detailsBlock{    
    text-align:center;
}

.numberAnswerTxt{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:none;
    font-size:85%;    
}

.numberAnswerTxtRow{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    float:center;
    width:15%;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:none;
    margin:auto;
    font-size:85%;    
}


.answerBtns{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: #666666 1px solid;
    color: black;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:85%;    
    }


#addQuestionBtn{
    font-weight:bold;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;    
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:85%;
}

.questionTextArea{
    width:98%;
    resize:none;
    font-size:100%;
}

.showGrid{
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;    
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-left:2px;
}

.optionTypeTbl{
    display:none;    
    background-color:white;
    position:absolute;  
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}

.gridTxt{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-color: #ddd;
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:50%;
    font-size:85%;
}    

.gridTxtRow{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-color: #ddd;
    float:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:50%;
    font-size:85%;
}    

.tblbody{
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;    
}


.tblhead, .tblbody {
    display: block;
}
```

​

Comment: The reason I am using percentages is that I believe (not sure) but percenages will alter width depending on screen size on any other computer, while pixels won't look good for every computer screen (small screen or large screen)